# Create table comparing data from multiple date periods

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, microsoft-powerbi

In Power BI I've made a table where I'm comparing values from different date periods. For example, I have the following columns:

- Last 7 Days
- Last 14 Days
- Last 30 Days
- Last 60 Days
- Lifetime

So I'm able to look at, say, cost per click during each of the periods. For various reasons, I can't use Power BI. Excel is ideal but I don't think this is a functionality of pivot tables.

Any ideas on how to create a table like this? I'm not limiting myself to Excel, so any application suggestions (preferably free) are welcome.

Comment: You question is too vague. Can you please provide an image of sample source/input data (6-10) records including headers and an image of the example of the output you want?

Comment: Sure. https://imgur.com/sTzMJ7J The data is on the left, and what I want to make is on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. If it answers your question, please mark it as answered.

1. This is how the results will look. The values in columns A & B is raw data. The values in `E1:H2` are derived with formulas (depicted in the next steps.

[image]

2. (I am using named ranges for this solution. If you prefer using literal column values, you can insert them in place of the named range) Go to the FORMULAS tab, open the NAME MANAGER, and click NEW

[image]

3. Name the values in columns A and B with "Date" and "Clicks" respectively.

[image]
[image]

4. Here are the formulas for `E1:H2`

[image]

E1: `=TEXT(TODAY()-2,"MM/DD")&" - "&TEXT(TODAY(),"MM/DD")`

F1: `=TEXT(TODAY()-4,"MM/DD")&" - "&TEXT(TODAY(),"MM/DD")`

Note, the formulas in `E2:H2` are array formulas and need to be entered by pressing the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

E2: `=SUM(IF(Date>=TODAY()-2,Clicks))`

F2: `=SUM(IF(Date>=TODAY()-4,Clicks))`